# viewport on mobile how to scale

Tags: android, html, css, viewport

I'm trying to set the viewport for mobile devices but everytime if i´m going to do that the height will be more longer than I want.

For example I've set my viewport to 1024px. This will fill my whole page on desktop and mobile devices... for some reason ?

I'm working with my LG G2 phone. 
Now if i´m getting on my page my device will correctly set the width to the layout.
But my problem is that the bottom is much longer as needed.
So how can I tell my phone that there´s nothing beyond the footer.
I don't want to make a sticky footer because it will not work on mobile devices.
I'm just trying to find a way to tell my phone that he can´t get beyond the footer... 
So the pages width will not be fitted at all but this is meaningless.

Is there a way to contain the whole divs and set the layout to 100% height? I need to tell my page that there´s no white space beyond the footer. There is the end of the complete page and my phone needs to understand that. The phone have to scale to the footer and thats it.

[my homepage](http://michael-kalinski.de/de/home.html)

Comment: I found the reason why my device will scale the page... in landscape mode the layout is completely fit but on portrait mode he cannot show the whole width so he need to zoom in. If I zoom out so he has no chance to creating more space on bottom. Ok! but how can I set the viewport to my phone?

Comment: Maybe is there a way to stop auto fitting x and y on Phone because the phone will always try to fit x and y. maybe there´s a to turn that off ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the height of your div as

```
min-height: 100%; 
height: 100%;
```

then add this to the head tag of your html.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you? Please see Mozilla Developer's page for your problem.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag#A_pixel_is_not_a_pixel